# Get and print informations from Json File in HTML website

Tags: javascript, html, json

I need to create a basic website where I have to print informations from a Json file. With Javascript.

What I would like to have it's, the picture of the results

But I have no idea how to do that cause I'm a beginner in Javascript. Can you help me please ?
Thanks a lot
Theo

```
{
    "number_of_results": 20,
    "results": [
        {
            "name": {
                "first": "Test",
                "last": "Test"
            },
            "date_of_birth": {
                "date": "1985-12-03T02:05:33",
                "age": 36
            },
            "picture": {
                "large": "apple.png",
            },
        },
```

Comment: you need a script that grabs each html element you want to add the data too and set its innerHTML to the data. you can use document.querySelector to grab html elements. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: StackOverflow is not a place for people to hand you answers. It will not help you learn for me to write this program for you. Also, there are many tutorials online about web development. A quick google search returned this https://sebhastian.com/display-javascript-variable-html/ which is a good starting place. After you have attempted it, if you are still struggling, come back and show your progress

Comment: what do you mean it doesnt work? does it throw an error? not display anything? Also, in the data you provided, none of the object have an email property or phone property

Comment: and both email and phone and strings? please show the shape of these properties

Comment: You should be looping over `data.results` not `data` as `results` is your array

Comment: You also do not have (or at least not showing) an element with id `myData`, eg `<div id="myData"></div>`, but try to get one anyway `document.getElementById("myData")`

Comment: Your for loop is trying to use the variable `data` as if it is an array eg `for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)` but it is the property `results` that is your array, so it should be `for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++)` and getting properties like email would be `data.results[i].email`

Comment: in the data you show, .firstName is not a property of any object in your results array. to get the first name you would need to do `data.results[i].name.first`

Comment: what do you mean a picture of the results? I think you should take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and update your question so we can help debug

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your data structure doesn't quite match what you had in your script so some of the corrections here (from your version) are:

- change `.firstName` to `.name.first`
- reference results array so `results.name` becomes `results[i].name`
- email shows undefined but that's because it is not in the data (at least not in your example)
- the image tag shows up with the right source, but because those are not full urls, the image will likely appear broken until the data is more realistic.

The following script should append both the div with the name/email and the image.

```
function appendData(data) {
    var mainContainer = document.getElementById("myData");
    for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = 'Email: ' + data.results[i].email + ' First Name :' + data.results[i].name.first;
        mainContainer.appendChild(div);
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = data.results[i].picture.large;
        mainContainer.appendChild(img);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works pretty good, but I would like to add a title below the image and before the first and last Name, and I would like too to maybe print 3 results in a row in the same line ant then switch to an other line and not one by one, line by line. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: I want to add after and below the picture, a title "Personnal Information" And then print every infos from the json.

Comment: You can add more `divs` or `spans` with this basic structure of `createElement` and `appendChild` and then use CSS to style them or organize them the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
function appendData(data) {
    var mainContainer = document.getElementById("myData");
    for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
        var div = document.createElement("div"); 
        div.innerHTML = 'Email: ' + (data.results[i].email?data.results[i].email:'') + ' First Name :' + (data.results[i].name?data.results[i].name.first:'');
        mainContainer.appendChild(div);
    }
}
```